# Am getting IndexError: string index out of range -Python

Tags: python, recursion, indexing, palindrome

```
def is_palindrome(x, pos_index, neg_index):
    if x[pos_index] == x[neg_index]:
        print("")
    else:
        return False

    pos_index += 1
    neg_index -= 1

    is_palindrome(x, pos_index, neg_index)


print(is_palindrome("racecar", 0, -1))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain in more detail what is not working. Just pasting the code is not enough. Also have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Am sorry Dominik this is my first question, I am getting an index out of range error when I run that particular code in pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

Your end condition is missing. You recall the function every time, so your pos_index becomes 6 ('r'). After that you should stop, but instead you add one and start the function again. So you get a String index out of range.

And a little note, for your next question some addition information or a specific question would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an error is because `is_palindrome()` calls `is_palindrome()` continuously and there is no stop if the word *is* a palindrome. The function will only return if the word *is not* a palindrome. Since there is no stopping point, eventually, both the positive and negative indexes will exceed the maximum index of the string. I would try using this:

```py
def is_palindrome(phrase):
    phrase = "".join(phrase.lower().split())
    index, imax = 0, len(phrase)-1
    while index < imax-index:
        if phrase[index] != phrase[imax-index]:
            return False
        index += 1
    return True
```

Note that this only checks until `index` is as close to the halfway through the string as possible (which can be observed by putting `print(index)` inside the `while` loop). That way, the code doesn't "double-check" the second half of the string.

Below are a few test runs:

```py
>>> is_palindrome("racecar")
True
>>> is_palindrome("bus")
False
>>> is_palindrome("a man a plan a canal panama")
True
>>> is_palindrome("AABBAA")
True
```

However, if you wanted to conserve the recursive nature, you can try using this:

```py
def is_palindrome(phrase, positive=0, negative=-1):
    phrase = ''.join(phrase.lower().split())
    if positive >= len(phrase):
        return True
    if phrase[positive] == phrase[negative]:
        return is_palindrome(phrase, positive+1, negative-1)
    return False
```

A few test runs:

```py
>>> is_palindrome("racecar")
True
>>> is_palindrome("bus")
False
>>> is_palindrome("A man a plan a canal panama")
True
>>> is_palindrome("AABBAA")
True
```

Comment: The OP's solution is recursive in nature and they tagged [recursion] but your solution doesn't appear to recurse.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to fix your code, and preserve most of it, I would do something like:

```
def is_palindrome_recursive(x, pos_index, neg_index):
    if -neg_index >= len(x):
        return True

    if x[pos_index] != x[neg_index]:
        return False

    pos_index += 1
    neg_index -= 1

    return is_palindrome_recursive(x, pos_index, neg_index)

def is_palindrome(string):
    return is_palindrome_recursive(string, 0, -1)

print(is_palindrome("racecar"))
```

Where the major changes are: an additional `return` case when we've recursively reduced the input to one letter or less; deal with the result of our recursive call -- a common recursion beginner error.

Since this is not an inherently mathematical problem, my inclination would be to get the numbers and mathematical operators out of the solution.  I would also treat the argument as a sequence, rather than a string, to allow fluid transition between a `str` and a `list` of characters:

```
def is_palindrome(sequence):
    if sequence:
        first, *rest = sequence

        if rest:
            *middle, last = rest

            if first != last:
                return False

            return is_palindrome(middle)

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_palindrome("racecar"))
    print(is_palindrome("radar"))
    print(is_palindrome("ABBA"))
    print(is_palindrome("pop"))
    print(is_palindrome("cc"))
    print(is_palindrome("I"))
    print(is_palindrome(""))
```

I expect a *recursive predicate function* for this problem to have three `return` possibilities: `return True` on success; `return False` on failure; `return is_palindrome(...)` a recursive I don't know, yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def is_palindrome(x, pos_index, neg_index):
    if x[pos_index] == x[neg_index]:
         print("")
    else:
        return False
    if pos_index==len(x)-1:
        exit()
    else:
         pos_index += 1
         neg_index -= 1
    
    is_palindrome(x, pos_index, neg_index)
     


print(is_palindrome("racecar", 0, -1))
```

Comment: From the name `is_*`, I would expect a predicate function, i.e. one that returns `True` or `False`.  This function does one of *three* things, it may return `False`, it might return `None`, or it might kick you out of Python!

Answer (score -1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects -

1. if the input string, `s`, is less than 2 characters, we always have a palindrome. Return true.
2. (inductive) `s` is 2 characters or more. If the first character does not match the last character, return false
3. (inductive) `s` is 2 characters or more and the first character matches the last character. Return the result of the sub-problem, `s[1:-1]`

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return True                    #1
  elif s[0] != s[-1]:
    return False                   #2
  else:
    return is_palindrome(s[1:-1])  #3
```

```py
is_palindrome("racecar")
is_palindrome("aceca")
is_palindrome("cec")
is_palindrome("e")
True
```

---

We can collapse the bottom two logical branches into one -

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return True
  else:
    return s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Finally we could collapse the `if` altogether and simply use logical operators for the entire expression -

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
  return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```