# Return in recursion

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, return

Is it possible to use the 'if' statement under the 'return' statement in the recursive function call? If not, what are the other technics/ways to compensate for it?
for example:

```
def is_palindrome(s, count=0):

   if count == int(len(s)/2):
       return True

   return is_palindrome(s,count+1) if s[count] == s[len(s)-(count+1)]

res = is_palindrome("rever")
print(res)
```

Comment: Side-note: You should use `if count == len(s) // 2:`, not `if count == int(len(s)/2):`. The former directly performs integer-only floor division, the latter performs floating point division then uses the `int` constructor to truncate off the decimal component (slower, and for divisors other than powers of 2, or sufficiently huge integers, potentially inaccurate).

Comment: see this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66568186/633183)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) `A if COND else B`; this evaluates to `A` when `COND` is `True`, and `B` otherwise.

```py
def is_palindrome(s, count=0):
    if count == len(s) // 2:
        return True
    return is_palindrome(s, count + 1) if s[count] == s[-(count + 1)] else False

print(is_palindrome('rever')) # True
print(is_palindrome('never')) # False
```

---

In this case, using `and` is simpler:

```py
def is_palindrome(s, count=0):
    if count == len(s) // 2:
        return True
    return s[count] == s[-(count + 1)] and is_palindrome(s, count + 1)
```

If you are worried if you would make unnecessary calls for `is_palindrome`, it is not true; `and` is *short-circuited*, meaning that `is_palindrome(...)` is evaluated only when `s[count] == s[-(count + 1)]` is `True`.

Comment: Possible, but `return s[count] == s[-(count+1)] and is_palindrome(s, count+1)` would be clearer.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that was my first version of the answer, but I edited it because the OP seemed to want `if` somewhere. Perhaps it's better to provide that as well.

Comment: @chepner ... and I did so! Thanks for the suggestion.